# Skip a Data Flow Component on Error

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

I want to skip a component of my data flow task, when this component throws a specific error.

To be precise, I read data from different source files/connections in my dataflow and process them. 
The problem is that I can't be sure if all source files/connections will be found.

Instead of checking each source that I can connect to, I want to continue the execution of the data flow by skipping the component that reads data from the source.

Is there any possibility to continue the data flow after the component, which originally threw the error by jumping back from the On_Error-Eventhandler (of the data flow task) into the next component? Or is there any other way in continuing the data flow task execution by skipping the component? [image]

Comment: You cannot [Disable Data Flow Components](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/410210/ssis-add-enable-disable-within-data-flow-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @praveen [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751870/skip-a-data-flow-component-on-error#comment32901514_21751870), out of the box you [cannot disabled data flow components](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/410210/ssis-add-enable-disable-within-data-flow-tab).

That said, I could see a use case for this, perhaps a secondary source that augments existing data which may or may not be available. If I had that specific need, then I'd need to write a script component which performs the data reading, parsing, casting of data types, etc when a file is present and sends nothing, but keeps the metadata in tact when no source is available.

Comment: Thank you, ssis unfortunately doesn't allow for skkiping/jump back from error handler (thanks @praveen), so i had to circumvent this by creating a scripttask, which read from the source of a connection Manager manually, and had to assign all columns to output-rows. For further reference, i followed [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060.aspx). But if you would put more effort into it, I guess you could also write yourself a [custom source component](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136088.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following based on what I understand:

1) Create a script component that will check which source to go and check

2) Based on the Source connection you can assign the Source